# Bash to close a Chrome window

Tags: windows, bash, shell, google-chrome, mingw

I have a script that opens a Chrome window in incognito by simply entering `C:\Chrome` this shortcut in `C:\` has `-incognito` in its properties.

I also want to be able to close that window from a script (maybe when the first script ends) and only that window because I have other non-incognito chrome windows open.

Is it possible to do this?

I use mingw on win10, I also have bash for win10.

Edit: when running `"chrome path" & ps` I can see it in the list.

Comment: You might be able to use `chrome.exe & pid=$!` instead of just `chrome.exe` when starting chrome. Then the processid is in the variable `$pid`. And than do whatever you want with it e.g. `kill -9 $pid` or `echo $pid > C:\last-chrome-pid`

Comment: Thanks but it looks like `pid` stays empty when I do that... @SamuelKirschner

Comment: Can you wrap it in a bash process `bash -c 'chrome.exe -incognito' & pid=$!`? Does pid still stay empty?

Comment: ... but do not run anything in the backround inside the `-c ''` part so the bash process keeps running and can be killed killing chrome with it? Also make sure `chrome -incognito` does not just fork of another instance on chrome. Also try `"chrome path" & sleep 20; ps`

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant about the `-c ' '`. I run this, I'm not sure I know how to read the output: http://imgur.com/a/LEYKk but I think the `pid` var doesn't match the pid of chrome? @SamuelKirschner

Comment: Looks okay to me. The pid matches the pid of the bash. As chrome is running inside it can be used to kill chrome. And chrome is showing in the `ps` output. Now you can kill it, but maybe just terminate (`kill` without the `-9`). Also try `jobs` instead of `ps` might be easier to grep the real chrome pid from there. Good luck.